# Django django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "ad.tcontainer_format" does not exist

Tags: django, database, unit-testing

I am writing unit test in Django, but I have problem:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "ad.tc_format" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ze", "ad"."tc_format"."y_size" FROM "ad"...
```

Important issue that is we haven't tools like **migrate** and **makemigrations**, all is manually create and own database routers class in addition in database all exists.

I think also about databases that I wrongly set default database, because I need two database to test:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': { # Here are users, permissions...
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'panels',
    'USER': 'admin',
    'PASSWORD': DEFAULT_PASSWORD,
    'HOST': HOST,
    'PORT': PORT,
},
'ad': { #  If I change name to default, then I got error - the ad name is required and here is other datas which I need
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'stats',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': AD_PASSWORD,
    'HOST': HOST,
    'PORT': PORT,
    'TEST': {
        'CREATE_DB': False,
        'DEPENDENCIES': ['default']
    }
},
```

I have tried duplicate database or created mirror:

```
 DATABASES = {
     'panels': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': 'panels',
         'USER': 'admin',
         'PASSWORD': DEFAULT_PASSWORD,
         'HOST': HOST,
         'PORT': PORT,
    },
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'stats',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': AD_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': HOST,
        'PORT': PORT,
    },
    'adnetsys': { #  Duplicated
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'stats',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': AD_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': HOST,
        'PORT': PORT,
    },
```

Or

```
[...]
'adnetsys': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
     'TEST': { 'MIRROR': 'default'}
 },
[...]
```

Do you think that problem concerns database routers or their names?

Comment: do you run migrations on ad db

Comment: Yes I did. I have the same data from dev like also in production and tables

Comment: can you manually check in ad db, is `tc_format` table exists or not? If not then you need to to run migrations on `ad` db